# .Net compatibility for different OS versions for WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I made a WPF application using C#, MVVM, Prism, and EntityFramework (talks to a SQL DB everyone has CRUD permissions for). I have a Windows 10 machine and all the .NET Frameworks and Cores I could grab up with Visual Studio 2017. The app is built in .NET Framework 4.5 and for some reason only 4.5.2 shows under prerequisite choices. The app works perfectly on my computer and two Windows 7 computers when I'm logged into those machines testing. I have an end user with 7 and one with 10 and both computers say they have .NET 4.6 or higher, yet there's a datagrid in my app that crashes the whole app whenever they click on it.

The fact that the app is perfect on some machines but not others has to be some kind of driver or framework problem, right?

Comment: Where is your code? How is data being accessed with EntityFramework? Is it available on the machine where the application is crashing, and how have you confirmed this?

Comment: The fact that the app is perfect on some machines but not others has to be some kind of driver or framework problem, right?

NO.

Comment: I was going to comment about constructive criticism... but I actually needed that knock to the head. I slept on it and it clicked on the drive to work to look again at the fact that it may be a per user problem. So I screwed up my own entry in the database, ran the app again and got a Null Reference. So thanks for getting my brain back on track Maciek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See above comments, it wasn't a compatibility problem, it was an error that I couldn't trigger when I ran the app because I was in my database as I should be, but other users were getting null references crashing the app. So... next step... implement Global Exception Handling.